# Reactive extension timer

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a HashSet.  Occasionlay, new values are added to this hashset.  What I am trying to do is have a timer remove each element from the set exactly one minute after it was added.

I am still new to rx but this seems like an ideal occasion to use it.

I tried something like this:

```
AddItem(string item)
{
  _mySet.Add(item);
  var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), _scheduler);
  timer
      .Take(1)
      .Do(item => RemoveItem(item))
      .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Removed {0}", item));
}
```

It seems to work ok (passes unit tests).

Does anyone see anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: what behaviour do you expect for AddItem("foo"); .. 30 seconds later AddItem("foo"); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your lambda in the `Do` call doesn't look right - `Observable.Timer` produces int values, but your collection is a `HashSet<string>` - this shouldn't compile. I'm guessing it was just a typo.
2. `Do`: in general your subscription should be done in `Subscribe`. `Do` is intended for side effects (I dislike the idea of side-effects in a stream so I avoid it but it is useful for debugging).
3. `Take`: `Observable.Timer` only produces one value before it terminates, thus there is no need for the `Take` operator

I would write your function as:

```
AddItem(string item)
{
    _mySet.Add(item);
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), _scheduler)
        .Subscribe(_ => RemoveItem(item));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to create a sequence to do this. You are already being a good citizen and using a Scheduler explicity, so just use that!

You could just have this for your code

```
AddItem(string item)
{
  _mySet.Add(item);
  //Note this does return an IDisposable if you want to cancel the subscription.
  _scheduler.Schedule(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
    ()=>
    { 
        RemoveItem(item);
        Console.WriteLine("Removed {0}", item);
    });
}
```

This basically means there is much less work going on under the covers. Consider all the work the Observable.Timer method is going, when effectively all you just want it to do is schedule an OnNext with a value (that you ignore).

I would also assume that even a user that doesn't know anything about Rx would be able to read this schedule code too. ie. "After I add this item, I schedule this remove action to run in 60 seconds).

Comment: Lol. I am just pointing out that this achieves the same result as the code in the question. The question wasn't asking how he could switch to a new library and be 'more functional'. As Flack points out in his question, the original code works and passes the unit tests. I am just suggesting that he didn't need to use a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using ReactiveUI, a class called `ReactiveCollection` would definitely help here, you could use it like this:

```
theCollection.ItemsAdded
    .SelectMany(x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), _scheduler).Select(_ => x))
    .Subscribe(x => theCollection.Remove(x));
```

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, don't mean to pick on you, but:

**ALWAYS DISPOSE IDISPOSABLES!!!!!**

(EDIT: Ok, not sure what the heck I put in my coffee this morning, but I answered with a whole mess of nonsense; I'll leave the above only because *in general*, you do want to make sure to dispose any `IDisposable`, but in an effort to make up for the babble that follows...)

<strike>That call to `Subscribe` creates a subscription that you are NOT disposing, so multiple calls to this method are just going to queue up more and more crap - now in this specific case, it's not the end of the world since the `Timer` only fires once, but still...Dispose!</strike>

If you really want to use this method (I think a better approach would be to have some running thread/task that "tends" to your values, removing when it thinks its neccesary), at least try something akin to:

Ok, ignore all that struck-out crap. The implementation of `Observable.Timer` is this:

```
public static IObservable<long> Timer(TimeSpan dueTime)
{
    return s_impl.Timer(dueTime);
}
```

which in turn calls into this:

```
public virtual IObservable<long> Timer(TimeSpan dueTime)
{
    return Timer_(dueTime, SchedulerDefaults.TimeBasedOperations);
}
```

which calls...

```
private static IObservable<long> Timer_(TimeSpan dueTime, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return new Timer(dueTime, null, scheduler);
}
```

And here's where things get fun - `Timer` is a `Producer<long>`, where the meaty bits are:

```
private IDisposable InvokeStart(IScheduler self, object state)
{
    this._pendingTickCount = 1;
    SingleAssignmentDisposable disposable = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
    this._periodic = disposable;
    disposable.Disposable = self.SchedulePeriodic<long>(1L, this._period, new Func<long, long>(this.Tock));
    try
    {
        base._observer.OnNext(0L);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
        exception.Throw();
    }
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref this._pendingTickCount) > 0)
    {
        SingleAssignmentDisposable disposable2 = new SingleAssignmentDisposable {
            Disposable = self.Schedule<long>(1L, new Action<long, Action<long>>(this.CatchUp))
        };
        return new CompositeDisposable(2) { disposable, disposable2 };
    }
    return disposable;
}
```

Now, the `base._observer.OnNext`, that's the internal sink set up to trigger on the timer tick, where the `Invoke` on that is:

```
private void Invoke()
{
    base._observer.OnNext(0L);
    base._observer.OnCompleted();
    base.Dispose();
}
```

So yes. It auto-disposes itself - and there won't be any "lingering subscriptions" floating around.

Mmm....crow is tasty. :|

Comment: Hey JerKimball, I thought that after Take(1) is satisfied, the source is automatically disposed.  If I add an OnCompleted hander, I see it get called.  When OnCompleted is called, is the source disposed?

Comment: @JerKimbal, this is incorrect advice, please delete it. IDisposable in the context of Rx does **not** require disposal. Disposing has a special meaning in Rx, to disconnect a subscription **early**. There is no memory leak, there is no problem with the sample code.

Comment: Sorry @JerKimball, you're usually good with Rx but Paul and Flack are correct - once the sequence is complete the subscription is automatically "disposed" (unsubscribed).

Comment: Oh jeez, I'm sorry all; I don't know what the heck I was thinking...you are of course correct - let me see if I can regain some face here with some editing...*facepalm*

Comment: AlexG, @PaulBetts There - hopefully I can still show my face 'round here :)

Comment: I mean, it's a quite unorthodox way of using IDisposable, it definitely triggers some knee-jerkiness :)

Comment: @PaulBetts I think what triggered my knee-jerk response was I just spent two days diagnosing/fixing a case where *periodic* subs weren't being disposed, and therefore spiraling out of control.

Comment: my 2c: IDisposable is for resource management not memory management. Sometimes your resource is memory, but not always. In most Rx cases the resource is the Subscription. and as the crew have pointed out, if you use Rx in a standard way you will get auto disposal.

Comment: @LeeCampbell I suppose a caveat on that would be "so long as your sequence completes"?

Comment: @AlexG My shame is great. I blame the crippling headache and recent-debugging-delve-into-hell. ;)

Comment: Yes auto-disposal only on terminating sequences! This is both sequences that OnComplete *and* sequences the OnError